# java 8 method reference behind the scene

Tags: java, collections, java-8, method-reference

My question is lambda and method references are all about functional interfaces. they are just providing the implementation of them.

Now When i write:

```
class Apple{
private int weight;
private String color;

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(int weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}}
```

and if i write :

```
            Function<Apple, Integer> getWeight = Apple::getWeight;
```

or

```
        appleList.stream().map(Apple::getColor).collect(toList());
```

how it is actually working my getter is not taking any parameter of Apple? because according to function functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> {
R apply(T t);}
```

it expects a parameter and return something and it should actually works 
when the getter is like:

```
public int getWeight(Apple a) {
    return a.weight;
}
```

i am little bit confused thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a `Function<Apple, Integer>` is not to be confused with an instance of an `Apple`.

Remember functions from school?
You have to take one element from domain (here an apple from `Apple`s) and it will be matched to exactly one corresponding element from codomain (here an integer from `Integer`s). `Function` itself is not assigned to any particular apple.

You can use it this way:

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
apples.add(new Apple(120, "red"));
apples.add(new Apple(150, "green"));
apples.add(new Apple(150, "yellow"));
List<String> colors = apples.stream()
                            .map(Apple::getColor)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(colors);
```

`Apple::getColor` is equivalent to a `Function<Apple, String>`, which returns color of each apple:

```
Function<Apple, Integer> getColor = new Function<Apple, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Apple apple) {
        return apple.getColor();
    }
};
```

Moreover

```
List<String> colors = apples.stream()
                            .map(Apple::getColor)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is equivalent to:

```
List<String> colors = apples.stream()
                            .map(apple -> apple.getColor())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

This is documented clearly in the Tutorial [Method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as *Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type*. As the object has the type of the reference method type then the object will be the one on which the method will be called. Means that:

```
map( Apple::getColor )
```

is equivalent to:

```
map( a -> a.getColor() )
```